# extends - how to ignore the children CSS on the parent

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I want to ignore the children CSS(`index.html` for example) on the `nevbar.html`

I have a navbar in `'nevbar.html'` and I am using `{% extends 'nevbar.html' %}` in the `index.html` there is also a CSS file in the `index.html` but it also affects the elements in `nevbar.html` I want so the effect will only happen in `index.html` and not the `'nevbar.html'` .
code example:

```
a {
    background:
       linear-gradient(
         to bottom, var(--mainColor) 0%,
         var(--mainColor) 100%
       );
      background-position: 0 100%;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-size: 4px 4px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-size .2s;
  }
```

this is apart of `index.css` `nevbar.html` also uses the `a` tag

```
<a href="" class="nav-item nav-link active this-is-navbar">Home</a>
```

but `index.css` also have an effect on the `nevbar.html` elements. This is just an example I could create an ID for `index.html` so the CSS will only work on the tags in the file but I have over 5 files to put `nevbar.html` in it and I can't create everything an ID.

maybe I can do that if something is in a certain tag than the CSS won't work on this tag or make everything bootstrap default if he is in the `nevbar.html` file

```
Frontend framework: bootstrap
Backend framework: Flask
```

---

```
code sample
```

---

backend if you go to `/`

```
 @app.route('/')
    @login_required
    def index():    
        return render_template('index.html', user=current_user.username, level = int(current_user.level))
```

---

`index.html` part

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}

{% block head%}
<title> Main Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}


{% block body%}........
```

---

`navbar.html`

```
start of the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">..... end of the code
     </nav>
    </div>
    {% block body%}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
<style>
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: put the common properties in the index.css and then all child css files can extend this index.css - but changes/properties which are specific to each of the children.html files should be in their respective children.css files...

Comment: @AkberIqbal I don't think you really understand `nevbar.html` is the base file and `index.html` is one of the children. I don't have any CSS I want to use in  `nevbar.html` I only want to use specific CSS for only `index.html` if I misunderstood maybe you can upload an answer with code?

Comment: I don't know the HTML/CSS scenario that you're trying to get help with... if you share a minimal working example, it'll be easier to help

Comment: @AkberIqbal exactly what the title says I have a few "children" with CSS of their own and I don't want their CSS to affect the `nevbar.html` elements. That's all what is going on right now is that for example, one of the children, `index.html` CSS is affecting `nevbar.html` elements, I don't want that

Comment: Can you share sample code?

Comment: @AkberIqbal Look at the code example in my question I explained my question with code in there

Comment: @Patch I think Akber means your HTML / Python

Comment: @Joeri I am not sure I understand what it is to share, I am just calling the `/index.html` when the user access the `/` and inside the HTML folder I have` {% extends 'nevbar.html' %}` but ill upload it anyway

Comment: @AkberIqbal Look at the updated question

Comment: @Joeri I that's what he meant look at the update

Comment: That's not how CSS works! Once you load CSS in your page it applies to the entire page. The only way to scope CSS (make it apply to a particular element only and not to parents nor children) is to actually parse that CSS, modify each selector by appending a unique attribute which you also apply to the element in your markup. This is typically done using SCSS/SASS/LESS and it comes as a feature in frameworks like Vue or Angular. I'm also pretty sure there are scripts out there which enable you to do it without a framework. But *"out of the box"* that's simply not how CSS works.

Comment: @tao I know SCSS but how can I make an if statement that will apply CSS only on the elements inside some tag, for example, a div tag

Comment: In practice: if you load a component which adds `div { border: 1px solid red; }` to CSSOM, you can't expect it to only apply to that `<div>`. Your div has to be `<div als5d3as>` and the css needs to be parsed as `div[als5d3as] { border: 1px solid red; }`. That's how scoped CSS works.

Comment: @tao So I basically can't use a lot of CSS because I'll need to assigned all of  the elements in the file a class for them and apply only changes for the class?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is unclear. But I can tell you this much: the idea of only loading a library inside a partial of your template is basically, wrong. It's a technique sometimes used to delay the loading of resources until they're actually used, but it can't be used to limit the scope of that CSS. You should architect your application considering all the CSS has loaded, from all the components and make it look as you want. Then you can play with only loading some bits when some components are rendered. But I wouldn't recommend it. You'll end up with edge cases and/or conflicts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212965/discussion-between-tao-and-patch).